# Create JSONObject with org.json lib in java

Tags: java, json

I try to create JSONObject with JSONArray in Java with org.json lib.
I write this JSON string:

> "{\"header\", \"array\":[{\"b\", \"a\", \"c\"}]}"

But if I try generate JSONObject like here:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Then finally I see this string:

> "{\"header\", \"array\":[{\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"}]}"

But I need see string `"{\"header\", \"array\":[{\"b\", \"a\", \"c\"}]}"`, cause this structure of elements more important. How can I correctly create JSONObject from string without issues?
I'm new in JSON

Comment: this is not even valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

Curly brackets (`{}`) denote an object, and objects are unordered. Therefore, the two representations are equivalent. If the order of the elements is important, you should use an array (`[]`) instead of an object: `{"header", "array": ["b", "a", "c"]}`.

(See [RFC 7159, Section 1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-1) for an overview of the JSON data types.)

Comment: This RFC also says that there must always be key-value-pair in objects